# What algorithm solves high-order unification for untyped terms in most cases?

Tags: algorithms, programming-languages

High-order pattern matching is an undecidable problem. That means there is no algorithm that, given an equation `a => b`, where `a` and `b` are terms on the simply typed lambda calculus, `a` containing free variables, finds a substitution `S` such that `aS => b`, where `=>` stands for "has the same beta normal form" (up to variable renaming). For example, given the following problem:

```
a = (λt . t 
    (F (λ f x . (f (f (f x))))) 
    (F (λ f x . (f (f x)))))
b = (λ t . t
    (λ f x . (f (f (f (f (f (f x)))))))
    (λ f x . (f (f (f (f x))))))
```

One can come with the solution:

```
 F = (λ a b c . (a b (a b c)))
```

Since that substitution makes `a = b` hold. My question is: what's an efficient (i.e., polytime) algorithm that solves this problem for as many cases as possible?

Comment: What I tried: I've googled and read many papers about high order unification, but most of them are restricted for the simply typed case and even for those I didn't manage to find a comprehensible explanation (most resources are often in the shape of a whole book dedicated to the issue, which often require a broad knowledge of many topics I'm not even aware of).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try nominal unification. In the paper [nominal unification](http://www.gabbay.org.uk/papers/nomu-jv.pdf), it gives 4 examples which are untyped $\lambda$-terms.